# Set Static Route between two countries (OpenVPN)

Tags: vpn, routing, isp

I have a situation that when i try to connect to a destination via a VPN tunnel connection, something goes wrong and the route to destination goes wrong and gets lost and never reach the destination!
retrying tens of times, it works and I can establish the connection...
It's an issue with the ISP, but no luck to have anyone understands to fix it.
Restarting the router, by coincidence assigns me an IP that connects easier with less attempts, but when this ip changes, i come back to the same point.

So, I though that if I can setup exact static route for the connection between me and the destination as long as the routing goes wrong!

I'm connecting between Egypt and India, the connection goes to Europe, west Europe, Amsterdam, London, and gets lost somewhere around there!

So, can I set a static route? if yes, then how? or if there any guidelines for it.

Comment: There are a lot of routers between you and the destination which aren't under your control, so establishing an end-to-end static route is impossible. Does the destination have a static IP address? Does it respond to ping reliably? Please don't add new info in comments, but [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1776620/edit) your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot.

The *only* way to influence the path beyond the immediate next hop is to set up a tunnel to some other location and route stuff over that tunnel (…in other words, to use a VPN).

For example, if you can set up a node at a 3rd location that doesn't have the problem you mentioned and is reasonably close to your normal path – e.g. a cheap VPS hosting company that has a datacenter in Egypt *or* in India – then you can set up a tunnel/VPN to that server, and then **run your main VPN *over that VPN*.** It's quite possible that the routing problem that affects your direct destination will not affect the path to that 3rd server.

(It does not necessarily have to be VPN-over-VPN; you could instead set up two-hop routing, with one VPN from Egypt to the 3rd server, and another from the 3rd server to India. It depends on the situation and requirements.)